# Exception Join in Zend\Db 2.8.2 (DB2)

Tags: zend-framework2, db2, zend-db, db2-400

I can't seem to figure out how to create an exception join using Zend\Db?

I see explicit [support](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-db/blob/adfe190ed0e6558d83558f7f68abfd7ccfda1e26/src/Sql/Join.php#L27) for inner, outer, left, right, right outer and left outer.  But was hoping there is still a way to retain the abstraction.

Is the only way to use:

```
$db->query('Select * from...exception join....')
```

Comment: Please confirm your exact Db2 version and operating-system on which the Db2-server runs.   "Db2 for i" supports exception-join syntax, but  Db2 on LUW or Z/OS does not at current versions, so for those environments a NOT EXISTS subquery can help.

Comment: It's DB2 for i, but I already know how to create an exception join in DB2 for i.  I was more interested in how to use Zend/Db to create the exception join (or equivalent) while utilizing the abstracted layer it provides.  I just wanted to avoid hard coding the SQL statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simulate an exception join with an outer join where the rows on the right side of the join are missing. For example:

```
select a.id, a.description, b.name
  from table1 a
    left exception join table2 b 
      on a.id = b.id
```

is equivalent to:

```
select a.id, a.description, b.name
  from table1 a
    left outer join table2 b 
      on a.id = b.id
  where b.id is null
```

I can't test this right now, but based on the [documentation](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.db.sql.html), you should be able to do something like this:

```
$select = new Select();
$select->columns(array('id', 'description'));
$select->from(array('a' => 'table1'));
$select->join(
    array('b' => 'table2'),
    'b.id = a.id',
    array('name'),
    $select::OUTER
);
$select->where(array('b.id' => null));
```

Comment: Thanks, I can't believe I didn't think of this.  Tunnel vision on exception join rather than thinking of logical equivalents...